# What's next for chat

Tags: discussion, chat, community

The Story So Far (tm):

The main chat for Sci-fi and Fantasy, [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), has been slowly creeping out of line with the standard expected of all Stack Exchange chat rooms. This has meant that it has departed from the [Be Nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy, at times, and this has recently come to a head.

**We want to guide it back**.

This means making sure everyone is aware of the [Be Nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy and the correct behaviour for a ['third place'](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7518/3804). Once Mos Eisley is unfrozen it will continue to be supervised somewhat more than usual by moderators, room owners, and CMs. Ultimately we want it to be an enjoyable place for people to come and chat. And like the rest of SE, we will rely on some [Community Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), which means users of chat taking some actions:

- [Be nice!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

  - Rudeness and belittling language are not okay - *If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.*
  - Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.
  - Don't be a jerk:

    - Name-calling
    - Bigotry of any kind.
    - Inappropriate language or attention.
    - Harassment and bullying.
- Be aware of others not acting nicely, and flag them appropriately (this will no longer result in rooms being frozen).
- If it keeps up, *disengage* — we'll handle it. If something needs moderator or staff attention, you can ping a mod in chat or use the [contact us](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page.

That last point is particularly important.

Remember, the reason we need these is that chat is still a [third place](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7518/3804) - chat is a public place. Don't make it uncomfortable for anyone, and if you do, be big enough to change the topic. Speak up if you see this happening, even if you're not involved. If you are involved, watch out and stop yourself short of offending someone.

I know that sometimes moving from other places to chat might feel restricting, you might not be able to share your normal topics or tastes in humour. But we know you can share something that everyone can enjoy.

Comment: And so Mos Eisley is unfrozen.

Comment: Thanks to Pureferret for authoring this.  He couldn't be here at the moment, as he's fond of sleep.

Comment: *Winter has gone*

Comment: @keen Thank you for favouring the English spelling...:-P

Comment: And please forgive small mistakes from non english speaking people :-)

Comment: “Be aware of others not acting nicely, and flag them appropriately (this will no longer result in rooms being frozen).” Ehhhhh. ;)