# How come our main chat, Mos Eisley, got frozen this time?

Tags: discussion, chat

[Mos Eisley is currently frozen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/valorum-himarm-poisoned-this-room-it-is-defunct)<sup>#</sup>, apparently indefinitely. I assume it has something to do with the users mentioned in @Shog9's banner, but is it possible that we be told - at least in concept - what happened in our room to make it get frozen again?

> If the rest of you want to create a new room for this site, think twice about it.
>   If you decide to do it anyway, learn from the lessons of this room.
>
> *—[Shog9](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37340712#37340712)*<sup>#</sup>

[image: Screen capture of the "mos Eisley" (now defunct) chat room, displaying information about why the room was "frozen".]

---

*Please bear in mind that this involves users being banned, so the usual "don't talk about what isn't your business" rule applies.*

---

<sup>**#** Link will only work for users with 10K+ reputation in chat.</sup>

Comment: I personally don't agree that our entire room should be frozen, especially since it seems like it was caused by two specific users. Why not block those users only?

Comment: "This time" - what happened the last few times?

Comment: Added the comment telling us to "learn from the lessons of [Mos Eisley]"; I'd actually like to learn but (as I wasn't present most of the times the room got frozen) I'm unsure what those lessons are supposed to be.

Comment: Both of your links are 404 errors for me. I don't know if that's because of my rep or because the chat room has been completely deleted.

Comment: @zabeus it's been deleted, so only mods and users with 10k reputation in chat can see the room right now.

Comment: @Mithrandir OK thanks hopefully the mods will answer here so the rest of us random users who weren't even there at the time will know what lessons we need to learn.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323484/a-cause-for-self-moderation-and-query-on-the-events-of-20-may-16) may be of interest/relevance.

Comment: Why?  Because everyone could use a little carbonite nap now and again.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the room got deleted?  Just move the last week into trash and leave the room frozen but its archives searchable so we can still see the useful content.

Comment: @b_jonas Because of [tomato blight](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10922).

Comment: So did life just [imitate art](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0znNiN0lYAQ) here?

Comment: In an entirely unpredictable turn of events, it became a wretched hive of scum and villainy.

Comment: @SQB The lesson, apparently, is to not discuss issues like adults and instead throw the baby out with the bathwater every time it irritates you.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The same thing. Small issues with a few users got a largely disproportionate response.

Comment: Those small issues were never handled by the folks there. I'm doubtful I'll win you over, but I'm a firm believer in chat moderation being a *long term project* and my views on it have always been about working together to form a healthier community. On the other hand, when I came in - and I'm a huge sci fi fan, I saw a room that would dismiss almost any concern raised, and had a few users hostile to a regular user who happened to be a moderator elsewhere *simply because he was a moderator*. I gave it two days, didn't feel at home, and quietly left.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek And if you want to know why people are hostile to moderators, just take a look at the room now. You don't punish the offenders when you do that; you punish everyone else. And for what purpose? None at all.

Comment: Right. Feel free to follow up on that accusation. Who did I punish? This is precisely the attitude I am talking about. Calling people Smurfs isn't nice. Feel free to give concrete examples, and try to use less insults.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Unless you're Shog, you didn't punish anyone. Read, then react. And they're smurfs because they're blue people. They can be Tobias Fünkes if it offends them.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm still getting an antagonistic tone. You don't happen to be Axelord do you? He was *mean* to me for no apparent reason. JUST CAUSE I WAS BLUE. And stuff like that is toxic man. And really, its not just about a few people, its about the culture that makes it fine to be less than nice to others for no reason, or to encourage crying wolf (Some folks were encouraging flagging for no reason), and so on. Also. Calling mods smurfs is not nice. Please don't.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's exactly who I am. And I have no recollection of speaking with you, nor could I find any in the old room.  However, given what's been happening throughout the last two years, I'm almost certain it had to do with someone overstepping the defined lines of policy and you coming in the aftermath of that.  If you did nothing to deserve it, I apologize. Back to the subject: Want to know what's more toxic than angry chatters? Moderators who make chatters angry because they'd rather inflict arbitrary decisions on other people than, say... clear their mod action queues.

Comment: I literally just came in. If you don't remember, consider, you're *reflexively* being mean to people just cause they're a mod. You're constantly ranting about mods still. I don't know man, the first step is realizing you have a problem.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek No one has literally just come in. The room is frozen and we never met there, apparently. You've never been in the new room. You've never been in Screening Room. I've been chat banned for a day by Art of Code for the last 4 hours, after he flagged my messages hours after the fact. *Want to know how I feel about random mods who think a heavy hand is necessary when dealing with already-finished discussions now?*

Comment: @Terriblefan - here's every time you said Journeyman's name in former Mos: http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=JourneymanGeek&user=175545&room=198

Comment: @Mithrandir Thank you! How do I do a search like that?
Journeyman -- apparently we were both wrong; we've spoken, and it was positive, nice things.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ^

Comment: I'm honoured that mine is the first name you associate with moderation, @Terriblefan, but I can't claim to be the moderator who suspended you yesterday.

Comment: @ArtOfCode As it coincided with arguing with you, and was in your personal trash room, it was a natural assumption. Is this a "you aren't allowed to know who did it" situation?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Apparently our conversation is being doctored to remove my points. Lovely. If the hostility on both sides isn't apparent yet, there's no hope.

Comment: @Terriblefan Your constructive comments are not being deleted. Only the ones that do little more than insult and complain about moderators are being removed.

Comment: @Null The comments regarding the situation already being taken care of, contrary to what Journeyman said, was neither of those. It raised valid points which keep being ignored because it's inconvenient to take note of the **fact** that we used the existing tools, solved the problem, and moved on.

Comment: @Terriblefan I've given you a little more leeway in these discussions than I normally would since I'm part of the group of moderators you are complaining about (yet I still need to make sure everyone is following the rules). I've only deleted comments that have been flagged, and they've been flagged by users who are not moderators on any site.

Comment: @Null You didn't close down the room after the fact. You have mostly stayed out of the chat -- *which is a great thing to do if you don't want to overreach*. In what way are you part of that group?

Could it be, perhaps, that the us-versus-them complex isn't one-sided at all?

Comment: @Terriblefan I am part of that group in that my name appears in blue in chat, and I've got a diamond next to it here. *You* have put me in that group of "blue people". I sympathize with the users who have been adversely affected by Mos' deletion through no fault of their own. I also sympathize with the moderators from other sites and the CMs who had to deal with inappropriate messages in Mos.

Comment: @Null Except they didn't. The users did. The users flagged the messages, and the messages were deleted. The users were automatically suspended. The discussion stopped afterward. That is dealing with it. Coming in 15 minutes later and crushing the chat isn't dealing with it.

Answer (score 32):

[A year and a half ago, I froze Mos](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7517/why-did-our-primary-chatroom-get-nuked/7518#7518). We don't need to rehash that again here; the linked discussion covers it thoroughly. At the time, we (the employees of Stack Exchange) were of two minds as to whether we should reinstate the room at all; eventually we decided to do so, with the hope that a bit of encouragement could avoid future problems. I've come to believe this was unwarranted optimism.

Lemme be clear: there are plenty of reasonable people who regularly participated in the room. This isn't about punishing the members of SFF, most of whom are still free to use chat; I froze and later deleted the room to correct the mistake I made a year and a half ago. If you've ever battled tomato blight, you know that once it gets into the soil there's no sense in planting new tomatoes there until it dies out; new plants will just become infected and die. Mos Eisley is infected soil; it is my opinion as a gardener and community manager that investing further time into it is a waste for both me and you.

A year and a half ago, I wrote,

> **Listen when someone speaks up.** If you're told that someone's uneasy about the current topic, then ignoring them is a slap in the face; be respectful of others (#1) and stop intentionally hurting them.

The continuing inability to do this was, to me, a sure sign of the room's sickness. In any active venue, things *will be said* that prove problematic to the larger audience; that's to be expected. How the group handles it determines whether they will continue to function. When yesterday's little episode crossed my desk, what dismayed me wasn't the off-color jokes - it was the fact that they continued after flags were raised, continued after a moderator stepped in to handle the flags, continued after the moderator attempted to reason with those who remained in the room.

There are many times more people active on this Q&A site than were ever active in its chat rooms; chat exists to serve them should they need or want it. A chatroom, promoted here as the primary social gathering place for the site, which becomes hostile or unresponsive to the larger community it purports to serve... Has lost its purpose and needs to end.

Comment: I saw no flags. I saw Catija (who was already in the room) raise a concern after I'd made a post, at which point both Himarm and I **immediately** shut up. There was no hostility and no-one was abusing the moderator. Both Himarm and I accepted that we'd crossed a line and took a short suspension on the chin. Neither of us (nor anyone else in the room) imagined that this sort of dramatic action would result.

Comment: I want to be really, really clear on something as the director of community management for SE. We're done talking about this as of this post.

Comment: @TimPost - I can understand where you're coming from. I've made my apologies to the users in another meta, I shall also find a moment to apologise to Catija when I see her on the site.

Comment: As one of the people active on the Q&A site but not the chat, the reason for that is precisely because of the impression (well-founded or not) I get of heavy-handed moderation, and the feeling I would have to very carefully watch everything I say lest dire consequences rain down. Since that doesn't sound very fun or relaxing, I've never been much interested. I suspect SE chatrooms just really don't fit well into the designed SE experience.

Comment: How "heavy handed" the moderation is in chat depends entirely on who is moderating, @Shamshiel; the lightest touch is always self-moderation. Nearly all trouble arises from a perplexing expectation that chat *won't* be moderated like the main SE sites; perhaps we should've called it "discuss" instead of "chat".

Comment: @TimPost that makes it pretty difficult to "learn from the lessons of this room."

Comment: Nonsense, @MissMonicaE. As I said above, we covered this exhaustively many months ago, and I quoted the critical lesson again for emphasis. Don't confuse a group of people playing dumb because they don't want to learn with an inability to learn; I've watched toddlers figure out these basic lessons of social interaction, so I'm more than confident the folks here can handle it if they ever care to do so.

Comment: So i guess i go from a 12 hour suspension 7 months ago to complete chat ban bypassing the usual escalation methods used by stack. especially for an in context non-offensive statement, that was, i admit flag worthy out of context.

Comment: Just for anyone watching, and speaking of “what to learn from Mos”: the belief expressed in this statement by @Himarm ↑ is an excellent example of what might get people in significant trouble in the future in chat, so it's a belief to avoid. Put clearly: messages are being expected to stand on their own in front of the judgement of the Be Nice policy. It's already been said a while back that appeals to context are no longer a defence of messages that violate the rules, so that's something to *studiously* avoid going forward.

Comment: @Shog9 I wasn't a part of Mos "many months ago," though, and what happened back then is difficult to figure out just from poking through the remains on Meta (I've tried). I didn't happen to be online for this debacle, so I only have a vague idea of what happened. All I can learn from this is Be Nice, which I already knew, and "don't rely on context." I don't have a clear sense of Mos's reputation, or the particular bad dynamics at play, or frankly most of the things that you're treating as obvious. I saw a bit of "sometimes people get irked at each other" and I saw the remains

Comment: @Shog9 of the wrath-of-god that ensued, and I don't know what happened in between. That's not because I'm a toddler or willfully obtuse (sheesh); it's because I'm not enough of an old-timer. (I am honestly trying to learn here, so I'm sorry if this sounds passive-aggressive. I guess I'm also hurt that you compared me to a toddler but I'm trying to keep that out of my tone.)

Comment: Again, I cover this in the post above (which doesn't mention "be nice" at all), and in the linked post from a year and a half ago, @MissMonicaE. As for the toddler note... A toddler touches a hot pan and learns not to do it again. If you can manage at least that ability to learn, you'll have no problems.

Comment: @Shog9 A good moderator ruins a room that does the same things other rooms do, yet consistently pulls itself back out, and *learns to not explode at the first whiff of trouble*. Incidentally, whoever put this problem in front of you needs to spend a few hours in the transcripts on all the major rooms -- they're high on hype. I keep being told you're great at the jobs we don't see -- but I don't appreciate you insulting the nicest people on this site because they don't see eye to eye with you.

Comment: I'm not here to moderate, @Terriblefan.

Comment: @Shog9 Then *why exactly* do you feel the need to come in and kick teeth in after  the fact?

Comment: You've been here for ages; if you still can't figure that out, there's no point in talking.

Comment: @Shog9 You've been here even longer. If you still can't figure out what's wrong with your method, perhaps you haven't been talking to the right people.

Comment: I talked to y'all for two years, and nothing changed, @Terriblefan. So, you're right; I'm done with that, y'all can take your fun somewhere else.

Comment: @Shog9 Great. We're all on the same page.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't think that expectation is too perplexing - take it from someone else whose been in your shoes for nearly 20 years now, chatrooms by their very nature breed a different type of culture and discourse than forums - in part because there's no tight focus and because of the immediacy of the interaction. People go to chatrooms to talk to *people* with similar interests, not *about* the interest, and that always ends up in interpersonal drama. Perhaps SE should consider limiting chats to the extended-comments-go-to-chat type.

Comment: @Shog9: Which isn't to say that chatrooms can't be effectively (self)-moderated - they can -  but they will *always* be substantively different and less "nice" than forums. I don't believe a SE Q&A level of professionalism and niceness is possible in any chat give enough users and time, regardless of the people and rules going into it. People develop relationships, cabals form, people want to have conversations about things they feel passionate about, etc.

Comment: @Shamshiel I'm sorry, but that's just demonstrably false. There are plenty of SE chats that are *exactly* the same level of Nice as mainsites and, often, nicer than their parent site's Metas.

Comment: @nitsua60 Meta is a place for argument. The normal sites, on the other hand, are specifically designed to prevent it.  Chat is somewhere inbetween.  Now look at all the chats you frequent, and do a search for a politician's name.  You will find things that are absolutely flaggable by present standards, and would never stand on the main sites (except Politics). Unless you count empty chat rooms (which most are, most of the time) it's not really as you say.

Comment: @Terriblefan The chats nitsua60 and I frequent are among those he is referring to which are the same level of Nice as mainsites or nicer. Those chats have been like maintained that way for several years now by their own users. If you're trying to assert that no chat can possibly be that good, well, actually there are chats like that. Those rooms have had discussions of politics and religion with total respect & civility (really). The incidents those rooms experience are few, far between, handled with diligent flagging and minimal upset or disruption, and minimal in severity.

Comment: @doppelgreener No, I'm flat out saying that I looked at the transcripts for his chats and they are worse than he postulates. Because that is the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 13):

It's not a complicated answer. Users known for being troublesome in the past continued to be troublesome in a room well-known for troublesome behavior. As such, the decision was made to ban the troublesome users in question from chat, and permanently freeze the room that is almost defined by its troublesome culture and seems to act as a magnet for troublesome behavior.

So in short, trouble got Mos Eisley in trouble. If you want a new room to survive and thrive in the way that Mos Eisley didn't, just ensure that troublesome users don't keep causing trouble (mainly through controversial statements).

Comment: I feel that what you're saying could be easily solved with banning the troublemakers - which was done. Why freeze the room?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Because rightly or wrongly, Mos Eisley picked up a reputation for being a room for troublemakers. It's continued existence, again rightly or wrongly, led weight to the idea that the behaviour the room was known for was becoming more acceptable. It isn't acceptable, and therefore the room has been frozen, as much to be mad an example of as to solve the continued issues that the mods were facing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reputation it has gotten is with a single user who has only had bad experiences with and negative insights into our chat.

Comment: @Mooz It was about more than one user; certainly there were a handful of names quoted whenever Mos issues came up.

Comment: @Mooz I don't agree. I've been active on Mos Eisley since I joined SE, and even I can see that Mos has slowly drifted into a less acceptable, more controversial place over the last few years. Simply put, it's a room where users felt more comfortable pushing the limits of the "Be Nice" rule - that's not on.

Comment: Be nice? I thought it was supposed to be a wretched hive of scum and villainy?

Comment: @zabeus Maybe that thinking is part of the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, was it politics? Actual harassment? Off-color material? Use of Big Macs as pizza topping? Jujitsu against bears? :) Part of the problem with "don't talk about the incident" is that it's kind of like that classic "you know what you did" scenario.

Comment: *just ensure that troublesome users don't keep causing trouble (mainly through controversial statements).* As we've seen in other chat rooms, making controversial statements isn't necessarily inherently the problem. In many places, people can have civil discussions centered on controversial statements. Historically speaking, for whatever reason, this has been a problem in Mos. Which is not to say that the users involved here aren't at fault - they know better. Both have been around long enough to know what sort of things fly or don't fly, and knew better than to say such things.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that our reputation has really only gone sour for Shog. He's really only see the bad sides (of which I'm ashamed to say, there's too many). Which is why he's applied this blanket rule or ban on all of us.

Comment: @Mooz that's completely untrue. Your reputation is network-wide, mentioned all over the place and Shog's opinion is shared by many, many users, myself included. I am an avid sci-fi buff and chat user and yet I always stayed away from Mos since I found it very unpleasant. And I am not alone, I have discussed this with various other users who felt the same way. So no, this isn't on Shog, far, far from it.

Comment: @terdon I have heard bad reputations about other chat communities and have not gone to them. My inquiry would be how many of those have been nuked?

Comment: @Skooba none have had as bad a reputation for as long a time with as many mods and CMs trying to change things being ignored as Mos I'm afraid.  In any case, the "waah, but Johnny did it too" argument is beneath you. Or should be.

Comment: Mos *already* had a bit of a reputation among a number of mods when *I* started as a mod. That's two years ago. Its reputation only got worse from there - it got marginally better for a short while after the previous big freeze, but only marginally and only temporarily. This is *in no way* about Shog - when the vast majority of network moderators hear your chatroom's name and say "ugh, *again*?", there are serious problems. Shog is merely the person who actually *did something about it*.

Comment: @terdon My counter-point would be inconsistent rule enforcement and arbitrary actions leave the door to such arguments. Don't get me wrong it is systematic in *any* rule enforcement position whether that be an internet chat room, or the highest levels of Government... "the only thing that was done wrong was *getting caught*".

Comment: @ArtOfCode As in my answer, I ask (rhetorically) how does one Role Play Villany and Scum on a "Play Nice" server, were there is never any real intent to degrade, demean, disrespect or diminish the reputation of SE?  Perhaps the problem is that while conceived to be one thing, it is being held to the standards of an Official Debate.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya Why are you trying to role play? Mos was not a room for role playing.

Comment: @Catija It is a metaphore, it sets a tone for how one can communicate. At no time should anyone think that tone condones the use of clearly offensive language, such as Racial Slurs etc. No, to the contrary, my attraction to the chat was that one could slip in a villainous reply for fun / playful reasons. And exchange example, Poster X made assertion A, I replied to it, Poster X said and if you believed that then I have a Bridge in Brooklyn I want to sell. I immediately understood and replied Lesson learned. I am positive that is NOT an example of why what was done was done. It is just an ....

Comment: @Catija ... example of what I mean. Role Playing has always caused problems everywhere. Some people just plain do NOT like it. It is my opinion, that in a case such as Mos, there should be protection, NOT protection from violating the rules but from others that do not like a group of people speaking ... differently than they are accustomed to

Comment: @Catija It occurs to me that perhaps I should ask you what you think Role Playing means. So consider that as a question :)

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya That's a *very* fine line you're trying to draw, and it's not a sustainable one. If you need special protections for your chatroom to work correctly, SE chat is probably not the place for that kind of interaction.

Comment: @KutuluMike And if you asked the users of the Bridge, or of Lounge<C++>, they'd tell you their rooms were perfectly normal too. (They're both reasonable these days, but in the past that certainly would have applied.) If you spend your time immersed in a particular environment, of course it seems normal to you - but to those of us who haven't spent a large proportion of the last few years in Mos, the kind of conversations that sometimes went on there were *far* from normal.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I think your taking the statement to an extreme level. I was trying to be very clear in saying that NOTHING should ever violate the rules of SE. What I suggested was that those that take offense with a chat room because it does NOT follow their view of a specific Debate process, needs to be taken for what it is. No they did not break our rules, Yes they are different from you. No we do not insist all of our chat rooms adhere to your view. Yes we do insist that all chat rooms adhere to OUR (SE) view.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya I know what you're saying, but I don't see how it relates. Things got flagged in Mos because they were *objectively offensive*, numerous times, not because someone had a problem with a debate process (more to the point, no debate was being held).

Comment: @ArtOfCode There you have me at a disadvantage I have not found anything that explains the why. DO NOT read that as a request to explain it. It was done. What this is about is seeing if there are constructive things that can come of it. Can SE grow from it.

Comment: @terdon As you were someone who got his favored site lots of negative attention -- yet not nuked, despite much worse behavior than was shown in Mos -- I find your ambivalence disturbing.

Comment: @Terriblefan I what? Where? When? You must be confusing me with someone else. I have never, *ever* done anything remotely like the sort of thing discussed here. What in the world are you talking about?

Comment: @terdon Two years ago. English chat.

Comment: @Terriblefan yes, again, what? I do hang out in the English chat room but I have never brought any kind of negative attention to it. Not to my knowledge anyway. I would also request that if you're going to go around accusing people of "worse behavior" than joking about molesting women, you should have some pretty strong evidence to back it up. Once again, I'm pretty sure you are mistaking me for someone else.

Comment: @terdon When it was just racist and homophobic slurs, you defended it as part of the culture. When it's stupid jokes that correctly get flagged and dealt with via the system, then horribly over-moderated after the fact, you jump on the meta post and laud it.

Comment: @terriblefan OK, now I _know_ you're confusing me with someone else. Either find me the evidence in the chat transcript (I'd be happy to help with deleted messages if you like, as a mod I can give you screenshots) or apologize and delete your comments.

Comment: @terdon [Remember that time a rape joke got one user suspended and that was the end of it?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=27808842#27808842). No? [How about when calling someone a "fag" was acceptable because of the culture of the room and the individuals?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=25509368#25509368) Not getting it yet?

Comment: I'd love to slander you, but all the things [*you've actually done*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=29922071#29922071) that would get us frozen or otherwise locked down keep getting in the way.

Comment: @Terriblefan thank you for posting something specific. I have no idea what you mean about a rape joke, there was no such thing there. Your second example is a misunderstanding, I am not defending what you think I am, please read the context. The third you are absolutely right about, that's not acceptable today. In my defense, the rules were a bit more lax then. I created [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58819), as I should have done in the first place (sorry), and we can continue this there (but tomorrow, it's late here).

Comment: @Terriblefan **Hey there. Speaking as a chat mod.** You're right that things that used to be okay are no different than what got Mos in trouble. The way chat is managed by the *owners* has changed since then, and you're right, those things would not be okay in chat today. We're going to try to moderate chat more effectively going forward, per the many MSE posts about how chat moderation has been changed. Just keep in mind that the flip side of that coin is that old offenses cannot be used to defend messages made now. Higher standards now make such comparisons moot.

Comment: Can we not use the MOOOOOOOOM but he did it argument? Yeah, mods are human and we slip up sometimes. Or we realise things arn't quite right and we work to fix them. Its nice to consider the past but question is, going forward, how the new chat room can be a *better* place than what came before. What someone did years ago isn't as relevant right now. I believe effective chat moderation is *immediate*, *done by the users* and sensible. I'm sure if you look hard enough, you can find me transgressing similarly. Let me know if you find any :)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek My concern was hypocrisy. I don't care about anyone's transgressions, but when they hop on the greater-than-thou train, they'd best have clean noses and covered asses. That is simply not the case here. This whole thing is a giant flawed argument against letting us moderate ourselves - which we were doing - by people who actively make situations worse. The comments were flagged, the people involved were out. This happens *every day, in many rooms* but they don't get a smurf train and freezing.  As I've told Shog every time he's shown up: you don't have to be there. We've got it.

Comment: Many rooms also do a good job at moderating themselves, *Everyone* has bad days but its all about the overall pattern of it.  Well, I think it was the right thing to do, and having a few days spent there, I can see why it happened.  Besides... who're you to decide who gets or dosen't get to be in a chatroom?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's not what I'm saying at all. I'm saying if you don't want to be there, you don't have to be there. We have it covered. We don't need people screwing it up because it bothers them, just to kick the can further down the road.  We have mods who moderate in moderation and we have users who know when something is going off the rails.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek And for the record, you know not of which you speak when it comes to improving the room. The room was improved. It was miles above what it once was. Overreacting outside actors do not change that.

Comment: @Terriblefan if you're concerned about hypocrisy then perhaps you shouldn't complain that Shog is being mean to your friends and then call moderators/CMs smurfs in your next breath.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not sure why people are treating "smurf" as if it's an insult, tbh. It's a common term for mods used around SFF and M&TV chat (in reference to the fact that mods have blue names in chat), often used affectionately or by mods themselves.

Answer (score -13):

First and foremost, I do NOT question the action that was taken. I was not there, I was not consulted, I simply found the equivalent to a 404 tab. I will NOT question those that made the decision.

I will ask for clarification, such that a new user (does not mean a new to life person) does NOT repeat what ever it was that did happen.

I chose to do this as an answer as opposed to messages. IF I am wrong to do so let me know and I will delete the answer. My goal is to be constructive, not to criticize.

@DrRDizzle, terdon and others.

I have no clue how serious the conversation was as I was not on and can not learn/understand what happened.

BUT to use another venue as an Example. Everquest creates Blue (No PvP) Servers and Implements Evil Races and Class's. How does one Role Play Evil in such a scenario? Isn't it in a sense Bait and Switch, Suck them in and say no you can not do that? I get that EQ couldn't do that and cater to the target market.

I think SE wants to be open and allow "Freedom of Speech". I understand that "Freedom of Speech" SHOULD require one to be responsible with what one says ON the other side of that I understand that IT IS POSSIBLE to tell people "If you do not like what goes on in here then don't come in". IF I revert back to EQ the Red Servers were PvP enabled and the classic answer was "If you do not want to engage / participate in PvP then do NOT COME HERE".

I understand that SE has a Big Picture of it's Users desires and interest and it's reputation on the Internet.

I understand that SE needs to steer the site to meet the goals it has established for itself.

What may be required is to establish that this SE is a Blue Server with "Play Nice" as the rules and not be overly concerned with "Freedom of Speech" and providing a form of protection from those that see speaking freely is not what should be done.

I have problems with every chat room I participate in and the parent Q/A ... Many times I see the question containing words, material, themes that may not be suitable for younger people and may pose problems for Parents of young people. The standard reply is the "community" (I assume the people in the chat room are the community) have decided to be very lose with ....

I am no fan of censorship, but I also am no fan of posting things that go after the reader of post's.

It is my opinion, that if one wants to make an example of something, then one needs or should also make clear what the point is and provide examples from "The Example" of what went over the line.

It is my opinion, that often times just deleting the posts WITH an explanation to replace them as to what went over the line. In addition IF there is a need to ban posters then do so.

BEGIN EDIT: The following section is wrong, it was based on a flawed understanding and should be disregarded.
Perhaps IT should be a LEARNED thing that one does NOT flag posts in such a contentious room, ever, even to the extent of removing the ability and changing it to a community event section, such as We will be airing "This Movie Name" on "This Date and Time" and would like to invite you all to join us.

EDIT: Phantom4 said "No. Just, no. The answer to people behaving poorly isn't "just don't let them say something is wrong". I beg to differ, the theme behind the bad feeling is the Flaged Messages. I may be wrong but isn't that the star one hits to "flag it'? Honestly I can be wrong so explain this. IF I am right then in a contentious room, isn't that a method to draw attention to the worst of that room?
END EDIT FOR DISREGARD

EDIT: "no, absolutely not. SE does not want to be open and allow freedom of speech, not when that freedom means "I get to say whatever I like and I don't care who it makes uncomfortable". A better description would be that SE wants to make sure the site they have created can be enjoyed by all people irrespective of cultural background and sensitivities. This means that freedom of speech comes a very distant second to civility of speech. – terdon"

I think your not saying anything differently than I said. Do you literally mean we are not free to say what we think here? No, you make it clear there are limits. I said "I understand that "Freedom of Speech" SHOULD require one to be responsible with what one says", perhaps you just missed that line. BUT if "literaly" are not free to speak, responsibly, then were are the guidelines, of what can and can not be said, so I can do a due diligence on not crossing the line?

Comment: Fwiw, people who aren't at least 13 aren't allowed to create accounts on SE.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that in the other rooms but I am not sure that SE has the capacity to verify and enforce that. That is not saying they should, just stating that if they can not does not remove their responsibility.

Comment: *"What may be required is to establish that this SE is a Blue Server with "Play Nice" as the rules and not be overly concerned with "Freedom of Speech""* This is already a rule on all Stack related sites.

Comment: *Perhaps IT should be a LEARNED thing that one does NOT flag posts in such a contentious room, ever, even to the extent of removing the ability and changing it to a community event section, such as We will be airing "This Movie Name" on "This Date and Time" and would like to invite you all to join us.* No. Just, no. The answer to people behaving poorly isn't "just don't let them say something is wrong".

Comment: SE has no "freedom of speech". I'm not sure where you get that idea. SE has "[Be nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)". If content is not nice, it is not welcome. No questions. No excuses. There are no rooms where this is allowed.

Comment: *'I think SE wants to be open and allow "Freedom of Speech"'* : no, absolutely not. SE does not want to be open and allow freedom of speech, not when that freedom means "I get to say whatever I like and I don't care who it makes uncomfortable". A better description would be that SE wants to make sure the site they have created can be enjoyed by all people irrespective of cultural background and sensitivities. This means that freedom of speech comes a very distant second to *civility of speech*.

Comment: The point of flagging is to call attention to a message that may need to be moderated, often because the message is offensive, or falls afoul of the rules. I assume it doesn't feel great being flagged, but the bad behavior needs to be addressed and corrected. By not allowing people to flag problematic messages, moderators/room owners are less able to find the bad behavior that needs to be corrected.

Comment: @phantom42 Can you explain the Link between Flagging a message that causes the Chat room to be seen outside the chat room and I will correct my edit to remove that part. I would like to incorporate your answer and speak to it, if I may.

Comment: Are you asking if you flag a message by clicking the star? No. That's not flagging. The flag icon looks like a flag on a pole. The flag is *next to* the star.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Thanks I got that from phantom42's message and would like to understand how a chat room gets negative views to an external set of judges(figurative).

Comment: Mods of any SE site, and any user with enough rep, who are in a chat room at the time are all notified of messages that are flagged - regardless of what chat room the flagged message is in, and regardless of what chat room they, themselves, are in.

Comment: I included a link to the "be nice" policy in my first comment. Perhaps you should start there?

Comment: This is a point of issue to many people - that mods and users who are NOT part of the chat community being moderated are being pulled in and asked to moderate without knowing much about the conversation at hand, or the room's culture.

Comment: @phantom42 I am trying to think this through again not to be negative or criticize but to, if possible, be constructive. IT MAY be possible that with the edited, limited information that what I think is being said is part of the issue, has no relevance. I thought I was hearing one significant reason for the action was the dragging the entire community in. You have narrowed this down to a subset. I am getting a feeling that I don't need to understand what happened (as a newcomer) and that leads me to believe the adage "Those that do not study History are doomed to repeat it".

Comment: @Catija So you may have piece of mind, I have read the rules you linked to well before this came to pass. But thank you for being constructive. I thought you might appreciate this part of the Rules "Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions. Don't expect new users to know all the rules — they don't. And be patient while they learn. If you're here for help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well to demands for help"

Comment: Just to clarify a point on the "freedom of speech" bits: the goal of Stack Exchange is explicitly to empower people to collect accurate and useful information on various topics, with each site dedicated to a specific field of learning; we encourage freedom of speech only so far as it works toward those ends. Individual groups are both empowered *and encouraged* to limit speech when it becomes counter-productive to that goal.

Comment: @Shog9 I am in agreement with what you said. I should probably edit my answer to state clearly that I do not question the action, I am trying to understand it and to make constructive comments if possible. Acutally the down votes and comments here suggest that "Freedom of Speech" is not acceptable, I am going to just take that as a reaction by some and not a rule, as nothing you said seems to be different than what I said "The freedom to speak, implies being held responsible for what you say"

Comment: My comment is as much for the benefit of those responding as for yourself, @Enigma. That said, I think your answer is a bit rambling; could benefit from some editing to focus on the core point you're trying to make here, and perhaps also formatting.

Comment: @Shog9 The problem (rambling) is I am swinging at unseen things. I would love to make the thing coherent but for me, with my knowledge, it is just to illusive and maybe I shouldn't have even tried. Meaning maybe I am so out of my league here that I am just upsetting the apple cart and should leave well enough alone.

Comment: I have literally no idea what you are trying to say here.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I am sorry you do not, as I mentioned to Shog9, I am so unaware of the issue that I am grasping at wisps and trying to make sense of things.  Literally, have no information, I can not present a coherent debate on this as there isn't much to debate. IF there was information then perhaps I would be saying the same things your saying.  I will repeat this, anyone that thinks the answer I made should be deleted, either delete it OR let me know why and I will delete it.

Comment: There is no onus on SE to continue to host anything they disagree with, and it certainly isn't a restriction of Freedom of Speech for them to remove it. [xkcd 1357](https://xkcd.com/1357/) is relevant here: *"The Right to Free Speech means the government can't arrest you for what you say. It doesn't mean that anyone else has to listen to [you] or host you while you share it... If you're yelled at, boycotted, have your show canceled, or get banned from an Internet community, your free speech rights aren't being violated..."*

Comment: @Robotnik I kind of thought this was all done and buried. I thought I had made it clear that "Freedom of Speech" here was not the "Constitutional" Freedom of Speech. I thought I had made it clear that the "Freedom of Speech" I used was constrained by the Rules of SE. Yet I see comments that seem to want to say I am wrong, based on an assertion that I am claiming some Constitutional Right. I just do not know how to make it any clearer. Perhaps you can offer an acceptable alternative phrase that conveys the same meaning but short circuits those that want to drag the Constitution into it.